# Azure B2C - Returns to Different Redirect Uri than requested in Authorize statement

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have just spent quite a bit of time debugging an issue that I found with using Azure B2C in a Blazor app.

I had been using the same redirect uri (https://localhost:7078/signin-oidc_B2C) for testing for a while with no problems.  However, I needed to change my url to https://localhost:4436/signin-oidc_B2C, and when I tried to login I started getting an error message stating that that the new Uri was not registered in my tenant.  Upon closer inspection, I also found that I was being redirected to the previous uri (https://localhost:7078/signin-oidc_B2C), rather than the new one.

Not sure if anyone else has observed this behavior, but it caused me to go down a rabbit hole to try and work out what was wrong with either my code or B2C.  However, sometimes it would just start working for no apparent reason.

I finally found the following link ([Azure B2C redirect url takes around 1h before taken into account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1181295/azure-b2c-redirect-url-takes-around-1h-before-take) ) that gave me the clue that it was a timeout issue and sure enough, I found that if I waited 20 to 30 minutes, it would start working.

Just posting this to hopefully save someone the hours that I spent trying to work this out. I was typically changing things before the 20-30 minutes so it failed, but if went to get a coffee or do something else for a bit, sometimes it would just work.

If anyone has any further background on this that you'd like to share, it would be good to hear it.

Following are some specifics:
My Azure B2C setup:
[image]

My AddAuthentication code in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme =  $"UNKNOWN";
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect($"{OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}_B2C", options =>
{
    var instance = config["AzureAdB2C:Instance"];
    var tenantId = config["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"];
    var domain = config["AzureAdB2C:Domain"];
    var signUpSignInPolicyId = config["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"];
    //B2C authority
    options.Authority = $"https://{domain}.b2clogin.com/{domain}.onmicrosoft.com/{signUpSignInPolicyId}/";

    options.MetadataAddress = $"https://{domain}.b2clogin.com/{domain}.onmicrosoft.com/{signUpSignInPolicyId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";

    options.ClientId = config["Secret_AzureAdB2C:ClientId"] ;
    options.ClientSecret = config["Secret_AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret"];
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
    options.SignInScheme = $"{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}";
    options.CallbackPath = config["AzureAdB2C:CallbackPath"];
    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = config["AzureAdB2C:SignedOutCallbackPath"] ;
   
    var scopes = config["AzureAdB2C:Scopes"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scopes))
    {
        foreach (var scope in scopes.Split(" "))
        {
            options.Scope.Add(scope);
        }
    }
})
```

Following is the authorize statement that was sent:

```
    https://sabrepmb2c.b2clogin.com/sabrepmb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=a955156f-XXXX349452527a
     &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4436%2Fsignin-oidc_B2C
&response_type=code &scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2FsabrepmB2C.onmicrosoft.com%2Fa955156f-b210-40a2-9398-95349452527a%2Faccess-as-user 
&code_challenge=x27PtwIXXXXXXXXXdsZwdSRaoSa-w&x-client-SKU=ID_NET6_0&x-client-ver=6.30.0.0;
```

and finally here is the response.

```
https://localhost:7078/signin-oidc_B2C?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=AADB2C90006%3a+
The+redirect+URI+%27https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a4436%2fsignin-oidc_B2C%27+provided+in+the+request+is+not+registered+for+the
+client+id+%27a955156f-XXXXXXX-949452527a%27.%0d%0a
    Correlation+ID%3a+bd47cefc-5c30-4171-9e41-155fbd4bb9d3%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2023-06-03+04%3a30%3a32Z%0d%0a&state=CfDJ8GgXXXXXXXXXSRaoSa-w
```

Note that the url of the response (**https://localhost:7078/signin-oidc_B2C**) is different to the redirect url (**https://localhost:4436/signin-oidc_B2C**) contained in the authorize request in the previous step.  This is unexpected and incorrect behavior.  After about 20-30 minutes from making the change in Azure, the authorization challenge will start to work.